# Implicit Type Casting from int and double to char

Tags: java, implicit, typecasting-operator

`char a = '1'-48;` doesn't show compilation in BlueJava version 3.1.4, whereas `char a = '1'-48.0` shows compilation error.Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The Java Language Specification, chapter [5.2. Assignment Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) says:

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression ([§15.29](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29)) of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the variable is of type `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

In the statement `char a = '1'-48`, the expression is a constant expression of type `int`, so the assignment is valid.

In the statement `char a = '1'-48.0`, the expression is a constant expression of type `double`, so the assignment is invalid.

It doesn't even work for a `long`, e.g. `char a = '1'-48L` will fail too.

The above rule allowing implicit narrowing primitive conversion of a constant expression was added to the language to simplify assigning constant expressions to a primitive "below" `int`, since all operators implicitly "raises" values to `int`. It is done to "undo" that widening to `int`, not to allow any constant expression to be assigned without cast.